# unable to debug past login in eclipse php with xedug

Tags: php, eclipse, codeigniter

I am using easyphp with xedug installed with Eclipse Luna as my IDE.

I have setup the Debug configuration (Default PHP server setup to point to my localhost), and I am able to launch the debug and hit the localhost server I want to hit.

I can debug through the first part up to the login screen (CodeIgniter loading my config), but once I login none of my later breakpoints are being hit.

I went through each of the 'Similar Questions' listed, but I can't find the answer.

Comment: I added 'xedug_break();', and still no hit.  I added 'die(),' and it dies; so, I know my break is in the right place.  Why will it not hit the breakpoint I have set or the xedug_break()???

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out.  I am not sure that this is the most appropriate way to do it, but it works.

Once I reached the login screen the 'DEBUG_SEESION_START' and 'KEY' as part of my url were lost.

I simply let the page load up, copied the 2 url parameters onto the end of the url and hit enter.

2 days of head-banging.  I hope this saves someone else.  I wouldn't wish what I went through on anybody.